# Ruby on Rails - New to Ruby help with rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a new user to Ruby on Rails and am having an issue with: `rake db:migrate`.

After I bundle install, the following comes up:

```
$ bundle install    
Using rake (0.9.2)    
Using abstract (1.0.0)     
Using activesupport (3.0.9)     
Using builder (2.1.2)  
Using i18n (0.5.0)  
Using activemodel (3.0.9)  
Using erubis (2.6.6)  
Using rack (1.2.3) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)  
Using rack-test (0.5.7)  
Using tzinfo (0.3.29)  
Using actionpack (3.0.9)  
Using mime-types (1.16)  
Using polyglot (0.3.2)  
Using treetop (1.4.10)  
Using mail (2.2.19)  
Using actionmailer (3.0.9)  
Using arel (2.0.10)  
Using activerecord (3.0.9)  
Using activeresource (3.0.9)  
Using bundler (1.0.18)  
Using rdoc (3.9.4)  
Using thor (0.14.6)  
Using railties (3.0.9)  
Using rails (3.0.9)  
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)  
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Then, when I try and `rake db:migrate`, i get the following:

```
$ rake db:migrate 
Could not find polyglot-0.3.2 in any of the sources 
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Anyone have any advice?  Thanks.

I am on ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.9

Comment: make sure your `gem 'polyglot'` in your Gemfile is not nested into any group like production or test

Answer (score 1):

Check where it's installed:

```
gem list -d polyglot
```

Run bundle exec to make sure rake uses what's specified in your gemfile:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score -1):

Ya..apparently the polyglot gem is not included in your gem file.
Also try doing gem install polyglot...
Hope it helps !
bundle exec rake db:migrate might help too..

Comment: Polyglot will get installed by Bundler as a dependency of ActionMailer -> Mail -> Treetop -> Polyglot.